# How to check license validity of another android application on google play

Tags: android, google-play, licensing, checkvalidity

I have two applications on google play and I want make some benefits for people who owns both applications. Is there any way how can I check license validity of the second application?

Thank you

Comment: `check license validity of the second application` is not possible in general. But you can implement a function in your other application, which will check it's validity, and report it back to you using `startActivityForResult()`, `onActivityResult()`. Have no idea how safe is it.

Comment: Thank you Vladyslav, this is good idea.